# How to whitelist a single logger in logging module

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

I have a python codebase with many loggers defined and that results in a hard to read log output. I'm looking for a way to filter out all the logers except for those that are of interest to me, e.g:

```
import logging

logger_A = logging.getLogger("A")
logger_B = logging.getLogger("B")


logger_A.error("this is A error")
logger_B.error("this is B error")
# logging.whitelist(['A'])
```

should output:

```
this is A error
```

How can I easily filter out all loggers except for one (define a whitelist)?

Answer (score 1):

You can set different log levels for different loggers using setLevel. You could set the loggers you are not interested in to CRITICAL and the ones you are to something lower such as DEBUG:

```
import logging

logger_A = logging.getLogger("A")
logger_B = logging.getLogger("B")

logger_A.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger_B.setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)
logger_A.error("this is A error")
logger_B.error("this is B error")
```

Comment: That would require touching every possible logger, which I don't want to do.

Comment: You could attach a new writer to just the loggers you want.